# How do i user open office in zf2 project

Tags: zend-framework2

i have included the openoffice downloaded file to vendor folder, but i'm unable to access it and it when i do

```
$odf = new \Openoffice_Odf($templatePath, array('CLEAN_REMAINING_VARS' => true));
```

it gives me the error

> Class 'Openoffice_Odf' not found

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to include it inside your script using include_path

```
require VENDOR_PATH.'OpenOffice/Odf.php';
```

or using a spl_autoloader